# How can I make an optical circulator?

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

I need to a single mode 1550 optical circulator at my lab. I have a varied supply of components, but no circulator. Any idea how I can make one myself? Perhaps using coupler and isolator?

Thanks.

-D

Comment: You would need a minimum of 2 isolators and will also incur $\geq 3\,$dB loss.

Comment: @Brionius It's really not electronics: it's *photonics", but yeah it's an engineering question.  To answer the question: read up on how a circulator works, then build a collection of isolators and splitters which match the guts of a circulator.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback. Although I will lose about 4dB using a splitter and isolator, I will use that setup as it fits my needs nicely.